# How to test method Jsoup.connect (static) using PowerMock?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

This is my code:

```
public void analyze(String url) throws SiteBusinessException {
        Document doc = null;
        Response response = null;
        try {
            response = Jsoup.connect(url).execute();
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Cannot analyze site [url={}, statusCode={}, statusMessage={} ]", new Object[] {url, response.statusCode(), response.statusMessage()});
            throw new SiteBusinessException(response.statusMessage(), String.valueOf(response.statusCode()));
        }
    }
```

How can I test this method using PowerMock? I want to write test to check that when invoke  .execute() then throw IOException and it catch then throw SiteBusinessException.

My code of test.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Jsoup.class})

Test(expected = SiteBusinessException.class)
    public void shouldThrowIOException() throws Exception {
        Connection connection = PowerMockito.mock(Connection.class);

    Response response = PowerMockito.mock(Response.class);

    PowerMockito.when(connection.execute()).thenReturn(response);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Jsoup.class);

    expect(Jsoup.connect(SITE_URL)).andReturn(connection);

    replay(Jsoup.class);

    PowerMockito.when(Jsoup.connect(SITE_URL).execute()).thenThrow(new IOException());

    AnalyzerService sut = new AnalyzerServiceImpl();
    sut.analyzeSite(SITE_URL);

    }
```

I got

```
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.siteraport.exception.SiteBusinessException> but was<java.lang.IllegalStateException>
```

??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a static mock of the Jsoup class. Once you have created such a mock in your test case, you can code your expectations using it.

Please see [mock static method using PowerMockito](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage) documentation.

Here the Testcase using Mockito and PowerMockito:

I was able to mock the execute method using Mockito + Powermockito (you are using both EasyMock and Mockito?) The code in the test case looks as below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Jsoup.class})
public class MyClassTest {

    @Test(expected = SiteBusinessException.class)
    public void shouldThrowIOException() throws Exception {
        String SITE_URL = "some_url_string";

        Connection connection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
        Mockito.when(connection.execute()).thenThrow(new IOException("test"));
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Jsoup.class);

        PowerMockito.when(Jsoup.connect(Mockito.anyString())).
            thenReturn(connection);

        AnalyzerService sut = new AnalyzerService();
        sut.analyze(SITE_URL);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an example for Mockito + Powermockito. You had mixed EasyMock and Mockito. But without changing your catch you will always get a NullPointerException, because the Response in the catch is always null if execute throws an exception!