# How to Mock Jsoup post call and reply back with constant response

Tags: java, cucumber, jsoup, mockito, powermock

I am trying to Unit test[Using Cucumber] the following code base

```
final Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(PERFORMACE_TESTING_POST_URL);
  connection
      .followRedirects(false)
      .method(Method.POST);
  final org.jsoup.Connection.Response response = connection.execute();
  final String ptJobLocation = response.header(HTTP_HEADER_LOCATION);
  message = "Performance Testing Job Triggered. It is available at " + ptJobLocation;
```

I tried the following solution inspired by [How to test method Jsoup.connect (static) using PowerMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658617/how-to-test-method-jsoup-connect-static-using-powermock)

```
//
// Mock the Jsoup mockConnection
//
final Connection mockConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
final Response mockResponse = Mockito.mock(Response.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Jsoup.class);

//
// Mock jsoup connect
//
PowerMockito
    .when(Jsoup.connect(Constants.PERFORMACE_TESTING_POST_URL))
    .thenReturn(mockConnection);

//
// Mock connection.execute
//
Mockito
    .when(mockConnection.execute())
    .thenReturn(mockResponse);

//
// Mock header Retreival from Response
//
PowerMockito
    .when(mockResponse.header(anyString()))
    .thenReturn("Test Response");
```

However I kept getting following error

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class com.dummy.package.ClassUnderTst
at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:46)
  at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:32)
  at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
  ....
  ....
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:40)
  ... 16 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

  at com.dummy.package.ClassUnderTst.<init>(ClassUnderTst.java:60)
  ... 21 more
```

Any help regarding this is going to be appreciated.

Libs used are as follows

1. Jsoup : 1.9.2
2. Cucumber Gherkin : 1.2.4
3. junit : 4.12
4. power-mock : 1.6.4
5. mockito : 1.10.19

Comment: and what's the problem ?

Comment: I have re structured the question. It should be informative now.